# I want to set a variable 's value from another php file

Tags: php, html

So i have dashboard.php

```
$value1;
$value1 = 1;
```

and file.php

```
$value;
echo value;
```

So i want to print "1" on the file file.php. How can i tell file.php to get the variable 's value from dashboard.php

Answer (score 1):

simply use `inlcude/require` or use `spl_autoload_register`. if you want to get the value from frontend, maybe you will use `session`,`$_GET` or `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to send a data to another page:

**Using $_GET:**

*dashboard.php*

```
<?php
    $value = 1;
?>
<a href="file.php?value=<?php echo $value; ?>">Go to file.php</a>
```

*file.php*

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['value'])){
        $value = $_GET['value'];
        echo $value;
    }
?>
```

**Using $_POST:**

*dashboard.php*

```
<?php
    $value = 1;
?>
<form action="file.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="value" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" hidden />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

*file.php*

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $value = $_POST['value'];
        echo $value;
    }
?>
```

**Using $_SESSION:**

*dashboard.php*

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['value'] = 1;
?>
```

*file.php*

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['value'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `include()`.

```
include('dashboard.php');
```